# How to put a video in a corner of another video?

Tags: video

I've recorded a tutorial video and a video from a camera, where I explain stuff going on in the tutorial. I would like to put the commentary video as a small box in the right lower corner of the first video.

I use Windows 7 and would prefer to accomplish it in a freeware program without using any scripts, etc.

How do I put a video in a corner of another video?

Comment: Which video will have the main audio - the bigger video, or the smaller (corner) video? Or both?

Comment: software recommendations are out of the scope of super user.

Comment: @FranciscoTapia Any recommendations where i should move the question then to get answer how to get task completed?

Comment: @tomaszs http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @FranciscoTapia asking "what program does blah blah" is off-topic, asking "_how do I do_ blah blah" is OK. This question is asking, "how do I put a video in the corner of another video" which is fine; the answer may involve suggestion some software. The point of the rule is to avoid questions like "what is the best software to edit videos", not to prohibit any question in which software would be an answer - which is clearly absurd.

Comment: @nhinkle I got the point.

Answer (score 12):

Your best bet *would* be a professional video editor such as Adobe Premiere, but you specified *freeware*, so I direct you to a favourite of mine: [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) or [avconv](https://libav.org/download/). (It's the same program, basically. The kind people in the comments might be able to help clarify which one is available for Windows 7. I use avconv because that's the one in my Debian repository, but the download for ffmpeg for Windows looks simpler.)

I am not sure whether the commandline interface falls under your definition of "scripting", but I really believe this to be the best and easiest (and perhaps fastest) way to accomplish the task.

Also, ffmpeg/avconv is usually known only for trans-, en- and decoding, but it can do a lot more.

### Examples

ffmpeg can make [these](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20mosaic%20out%20of%20several%20input%20videos) mosaics, [place a video on a static background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748808/how-to-place-a-video-at-a-specific-location-on-top-a-larger-static-background-im), [overlay on top of another video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698372/ffmpeg-overlay-video-on-top-of-another-video) (but that one looks like it's in C#) and [overlay two videos on top of each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215001/paste-one-video-to-another-on-top-layer) (commandline).

The first link about the mosaics is a tutorial from ffmpeg.org, so it explains a lot of what is going on.

### Specific solution

ffmpeg/avconv is very powerful, but sometimes it can take a while to figure out precisely what you want to do and how you want to do it. I am now going to attempt to construct a specific solution.

Say the video is in standard HD 1920x1080, ratio 16:9.

First, you need to figure out the size of the overlay video. You probably would have wanted to see this visually, but you can try this process multiple times until you are satisfied. If the two videos are the same size, you can perhaps make the overlay an quarter of the horizontal size of the background. The overlay would then be 1920/4=480 wide and (1920/4)*(9/16)=270 high at coordinates (from top left) x=1920-480=1440 and y=1080-270=810.

This is just some Mathematics because I wanted to make the video precisely a quarter of the horizontal size. You can just specify the size and position of the overlay.

Using filter_complex ([documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html)), set the overlay position:

```
-filter_complex overlay=1440:810
```

And adding the scale filter for the overlay:

```
-filter_complex "[1] scale=480:270 [over]; [0][over] overlay=1440:810"
```

(The numbers in square brackets specify which of the inputs is acted on.) (The scale-filter needs to go before the overlay filter, otherwise the overlay-video will flow outside the background/output and cause an error.)

Constructing the entire command would then be as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i background.movie -i overlay.movie -filter_complex "[1] scale=480:270 [over]; [0][over] overlay=1440:810" output.movie
```

("-i" designates inputs; the output is the only other argument without the "-" option-indicator.)

### Method

1. Install ffmpeg/avconv
2. Copy and paste the command into your commandline interface
3. Change the input and output files. (You could first navigate to the specific folder and then just run with the filenames, or you can specify the full path in the command.) (ffmpeg/avconv automatically selects the format from the output filename extension, so just change it to e.g. ".mp4".)
4. Change the resolutions/sizes.
5. Execute the command.

### Testing

I have tested this with avconv with precisely the same syntax (with other resolutions in ratio 4:3, just because that was the default) and was able to change this

[image: Background image]

and this

[image: Overlay image]

into this

[image: Resulting image]

(These are VLC snapshots.)

### Thanks and Bibliography

- As you might have seen, I borrowed heavily from user [blahdiblah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85950/blahdiblah) (in the [second example link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748808/how-to-place-a-video-at-a-specific-location-on-top-a-larger-static-background-im)) who knows more than me about these things - thanks!
- I also consulted the documentation on [ffmpeg.org](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of tools you can use (all of which will be opinion based as many can do the same tasks, some better than others)... My answer is based on answering your question, and I am not recommending you use the software, merely that some short research will find your answer... try it, see if it works for you...

A useful video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dWSRL9Xaigs) where someone has used VirtualDub and AviSynth (both free and open source) to achieve a PIP (Picture-in-Picture) of two video files. A very basic script was used, but it was about 3 lines and provided the input files and the PIP coordinates (where the PIP video should be overlayed)).

Answer (score 0):

I would use [blender](http://www.blender.org/) to accomplish this.  A quick search for "blender picture-in-picture" came up with [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgibzMyp_R8) that outlines the necessary steps.  Unfortunately that video tutorial is aimed at intermediate users, so it leaves out some of the steps that a complete novice would need explained (like arranging the windows for Video Editing, and adding the movie strips)

Answer (score -1):

I've used the trial version of Camtasia by Techsmith in the past. Depending on how long this project is going on, or how long you will need the software, this could be a viable option. If you're just producting the one video, the trial period is free and it's a very good program for editing videos like that.